# Listar um restaurante, a partir do item que está salvo no banco de dados, dentro de uma tabela Carrinho

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Gostaria de listar um Restaurante, onde tenham sido salvos itens desse mesmo restaurante dentro do carrinho. Sendo que, ao salvar o produto do carrinho, ele puxa com ele o ID do restaurante. Segue o meu controller que eu fiz, porém não deu certo:

```
public ActionResult SelectRestaurante(int? id)
    {
        Carrinho carrinho = new Carrinho();

        carrinho.produtos = db.Produtos.Find(id);

        var restaurantes = db.Restaurantes.Include(r => r.Cozinha).Where(x => x.RestauranteID == carrinho.produtos.RestauranteID);
        return View(restaurantes.ToList());
    }
```

Classes:

```
public class Carrinho
{
    [Key]
    public int CarrinhoID { get; set; }

    // FKs;
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Cliente")]
    [DisplayName("Cliente ID")]
    public int ClienteID { get; set; }

    public virtual Cliente cliente { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Produto")]
    [DisplayName("ProdutoID")]
    public int ProdutoID { get; set; }

    public virtual Produto produtos { get; set; }


}

public class Produto
{
    [Key]
    public int ProdutoID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o nome do produto")]
    [DisplayName("Produto")]
    [StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "O nome do produto deve ter entre 5 a 20 caracteres")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha a descrição do produto")]
    [DisplayName("Descrição")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "O nome do produto deve ter entre 5 a 50 caracteres")]
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Foto")]
    public string Foto { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o valor do produto")]
    [DisplayName("Valor R$")]
    public decimal Valor { get; set; }

    //relacionamentos
    public int RestauranteID { get; set; }
    public virtual Restaurante Restaurante { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Carrinho> Carrinhos { get; set; }
}

 public abstract class Restaurante
{
    [Key]
    public int RestauranteID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o nome do Restaurante")]
    [DisplayName("Restaurante")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "O nome do restaurante deve ter entre 5 e 50 caracteres.")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o tipo de cozinha")]
    [DisplayName("Cozinha")]
    public int CozinhaID { get; set; }
    public virtual Cozinha Cozinha { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o telefone")]
    [DisplayName("Telefone")]
    [StringLength(12, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = "O número de telefone deve haver 12 caracteres.")]
    public string Telefone { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o CNPJ")]
    [DisplayName("Cnpj")]
    [StringLength(18, MinimumLength = 18, ErrorMessage = "O CNPJ deve haver no máximo, 18 caracteres.")]
    public string Cnpj { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o CEP")]
    [DisplayName("CEP")]
    [StringLength(9, MinimumLength = 8, ErrorMessage = "O CEP deve haver no máximo 9 caracteres.")]
    public string Cep { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha a Cidade")]
    [DisplayName("Cidade")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "A cidade deve ter entre 5 e 50 caracteres.")]
    public string Cidade { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o Estado")]
    [DisplayName("Estado")]
    [StringLength(2, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "A sigla do estado deve haver 2 caracteres.")]
    public string Estado { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o Bairro")]
    [DisplayName("Bairro")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "O bairro deve ter entre 5 e 50 caracteres.")]
    public string Bairro { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha a Rua")]
    [DisplayName("Rua")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "A rua deve ter entre 5 e 50 caracteres.")]
    public string Rua { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha a número do estabelecimento")]
    [DisplayName("Número")]
    public int NumRua { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o nome do responsável pelo estabelecimento")]
    [DisplayName("Nome")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "O nome do responsável deve ter entre 5 e 50 caracteres.")]
    public string NomeResp { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o sobrenome do responsável pelo estabelecimento")]
    [DisplayName("Sobrenome")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "O sobrenome do responsável deve ter entre 5 e 50 caracteres.")]
    public string SobrenomeResp { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o Email")]
    [DisplayName("Email")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "E-mail inválido")]
    [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "O email deve ter entre 3 e 255 caracteres.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o Celular")]
    [DisplayName("Telefone")]
    [StringLength(15, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = "O número de celular deve haver entre 10 e 15 caracteres.")]
    public string Celular { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha a senha")]
    [DisplayName("Senha")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "A senha deve ter entre 3 e 50 caracteres.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Senha { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha a senha")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [DisplayName("Confirmar Senha")]
    [Compare("Senha", ErrorMessage = "A senha e a confirmação de senha estão diferentes!")]
    public string ConfirmarSenha { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Foto")]
    public string Foto { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Por favor, coloque o código da classe também :D

Comment: Tá ai! Adicionei do Carrinho e do Produto. =D

Comment: A classe restaurante possui um ICollection<Produto>? Seria bom vc postar o código da classe Restaurante tbm.

Comment: Sim, ela possui. Eu disse isso lá em cima. Vou colocar.

Comment: Você não descreveu o problema! O que está errado? Que resultado você esperava?

Comment: Tá escrito lá em cima, cara... eu quero que apareça o restaurante(s), que estejam com o ID no produto, que já estão salvos no banco de dados. Só ler o código que da pra saber.

Comment: Suas relações estão erradas, estão 1 para 1 o certo seria N para M. Do jeito que está, um carrinho só pode ter um produto, um produto só pode existir em 1 restaurante, se existir em 2 serão 2 produtos diferentes....arruma isso primeiro! E para pegar o restaurante do Carrinho, basta fazer Carrinho.produtos.Restaurante do jeito que está hoje